# WebpackError: ReferenceError: Image is not defined (during "gatsby build" by "gatsby develop" works fine)

Tags: build, gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

```
**failed Building static HTML for pages - 3.572s**

 ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed for path "/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  38 |             thrershold: 0,
  39 |             disableDragImage: function () {
> 40 |                 var transparent = new Image();
     | ^
  41 |                 transparent.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7';      
  42 |                 return transparent;
  43 |             }()


  ***WebpackError: ReferenceError: Image is not defined***
  
  - index.js:40 
    node_modules/react-carousel-slider/es/index.js:40:1
  
  - index.js:43 
    node_modules/react-carousel-slider/es/index.js:43:14
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following snippet in your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /react-carousel-slider/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Some [third-party dependencies use some global objects like `window` or `document`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) to make their stuff. This is perfectly valid when running `gatsby develop` since the code is compiled on the browser-side. However, `gatsby build` occurs in the server-side (your Node server) where obviously no window, because it's not even already defined yet.

That's why you need to add a `null` loader to the webpack's config by calling the [`onCreateWebpackConfig`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#onCreateWebpackConfig) API, to avoid the dependency transpilation on the server-side.

The rule is a regular expression (that's why is between slashes) and literally, the `test` value matches a path in your `node_modules` folder to look for the dependency location, so, you must put there the exact folder name.